# SQL query doesn't display results if thumbnail isn't set for post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using the following query to select some data from my wp database, based on the current users ID and display a box with the featured image and post title:

```
SELECT  ( SELECT guid 
        FROM ch_posts 
        WHERE ID = m.meta_value ) AS url, 
     p.ID, p.post_title, p.guid
FROM ch_posts p, ch_postmeta m
WHERE  p.post_type =  'product'
AND p.post_status =  'publish'
AND p.id = m.post_id
AND m.meta_key =  '_thumbnail_id'
AND p.post_author = $user_ID
```

The problem I am having is that the box only shows if there is a thumbnail present. If no thumbnail is set for the post then I don't get any results.

Anybody know how I can show my box even if there is no thumbnail?

Comment: What errors did you get? If no errors displayed please post your PHP error Log. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have used `AND` condition, thats why you are getting result with only thumbnail

```
SELECT  ( SELECT guid FROM ch_posts WHERE ID = m.meta_value ) AS url, p.ID, p.post_title, p.guid
    FROM ch_posts p, ch_postmeta m

    WHERE  p.post_type =  'product'
    AND p.post_status =  'publish'
    AND p.id = m.post_id
    OR m.meta_key =  '_thumbnail_id'// Or instead of AND

    AND p.post_author = $user_ID
```